# Pandas - Converting columns in percentage based on first columns value

Tags: pandas, percentage

There is a data frame with totals and counts:

```
pd.DataFrame({
            'categorie':['a','b','c'],
            'total':[100,1000,500],
            'x':[10,100,5],
            'y':[100,1000,500]
         })
```

| categorie | total | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 100 | 10 | 100 |
| b | 1000 | 100 | 1000 |
| c | 500 | 5 | 500 |

I like to convert the counted columns into percentage based on the totals:

| categorie | total | x% | y% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 100 | 10 | 100 |
| b | 1000 | 10 | 100 |
| c | 500 | 1 | 100 |

Following will work for a series:

```
(100 * df['x'] / df['total']).round(1)
```

How to apply this for all columns in the data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `div()`,`mul()` and `astype()` method:

```
df[['x%','y%']]=df[['x','y']].div(df['total'],axis=0).mul(100).astype(int)
```

output of `df`:

```
    categorie   total   x       y       x%      y%
0   a           100     10      100     10      100
1   b           1000    100     1000    10      100
2   c           500     5       500     1       100
```

Comment: That works great and I will inspect the methods in detail. Thanks, made my day.